# Azure MySql Exception: The connection string may not be right. Please visit portal for references

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, azure

I have a problem with MySql connection to Azure MySql server from my .net framework application.

Error is

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Authentication to host 'myserver-mysql.mysql.database.azure.com' for user 'username@myserver-mysql' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: The connection string may not be right. Please visit portal for references.
  Source=MySql.Data
  StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(String authMethod, Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at EfTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...

Inner Exception 1:
MySqlException: The connection string may not be right. Please visit portal for references.
```

The console app to reproduce the issue

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = "myserver-mysql.mysql.database.azure.com";
        var database = "e10bf91fc2a8e281d06fecf752e2a592";
        var user = "username@myserver-mysql";
        var password = "mypassword";
        var port = "3306";
        var sslM = "preferred";

        var connectionString = String.Format("server={0};port={1};user id={2}; password={3}; database={4}; SslMode={5}", server, port, user, password, database, sslM);

        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            connection.Ping();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

packages

```
<packages>
  <package id="Google.Protobuf" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="8.0.15" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

I also tried exact same connection string from Azure Portal
`$"Server=myserver-mysq.mysql.database.azure.com; Port=3306; Database={database}; Uid=username@myserver-mysq; Pwd={password}; SslMode=Preferred;";` but no chance.

Can anyone point me to what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string format:

```
var connectionString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Uid={2};Pwd={3};Database={4};SslMode={5}", server, port, user, password, database, sslM);
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't help either. I managed to make it work by replacing MySql.Data package with MySqlConnector by Bradley Grainger. Sadly the last one does not have EF package, so I either find a fix for this one or create my own

Comment: @xakz I'm not sure if Oracle's MySql.Data is compatible with Azure Database for MySQL. If you can use EF.Core, then https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql should work for you. Otherwise, there is no "classic" EF implementation built on top of MySqlConnector, sorry.